# Speeding up search with neo4j

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, cypher

I have an embedded neo4j server with ruby on rails.

These are the configurations:

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=25M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=240M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=230M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=1200M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=130M

wrapper.java.initmemory=1024
wrapper.java.maxmemory=2048
```

There are around ~15lakhs nodes for the movie in the database.

Movie node has a property `lowercase_indexed_name` which is indexed and is lowercase of property `name` to handle case sensitive issues with indexing.

Below are the time taken by following queries to execute an autocomplete search..

1.

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)
WHERE movie.lowercase_indexed_name =~ 'SEARCH_STRING_IN_LOWER_CASE.*'
RETURN movie
```

takes 2500ms.

2.

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)
WHERE movie.name =~ 'SEARCH_STRING_IN_PROPER_CASE.*'
RETURN movie
```

also takes 2500ms.

3.

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)
WHERE movie.lowercase_indexed_name = 'EXACT_STRING_IN_LOWER_CASE'
RETURN movie
```

takes 84ms.

Looking at query 1 and 2 states that indexing doesn't work for regex matching.

What's the way around to speed up the first query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, there is no schema index for full-text-searches.

You can use the legacy full-text-indexes for that, see my blog post: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/

Comment: Hi, Also is there a way to handle `spelling errors` or a `did you mean` kind of feature with this in case the query doesn't match any result?

Answer (score 1):

I've taken to using the [Searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) gem in my Neo4j.rb projects to handle full-text searches. A recent commit to the gem on github provides compatibility with Searchkick, just make sure you're using the IdProperty system. You can post an issue on https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j if you need a hand with any of this.

Comment: Hi, This looks interesting. But I am using `neography`. How to integrate `searchkick` with `neography` https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography?

Comment: Ahh, my mistake. I don't know why I assumed Neo4j.rb. You won't be able to integrate it with Neography, though I'm sure there's a way to use Elasticsearch (which Searchkick uses) with your data.